# How can increase the fuel-efficiency of my Vespa bike?

Tags: fuel-system, fuel-tank, scooter

My factory Vespa bike can travel around 150 KM with its 200 CC engine and 8 lt. of gasoline. What are the suggested modifications to increase the fuel efficiency? Without modifications like getting a bigger fuel tank.

Comment: Judging by [this set of data](http://www.fuelly.com/motorcycle/vespa/px200), PX200 averages about 4 L/100 km, so there is not much to do besides modifying your driving style. Also, it very much depends on where you riding (town or country). [This guy](http://www.fuelly.com/driver/c95052/px200) on 1998 PX200 routinely got over 200 km with 3.2 L/100 km, possibly because of doing long voyages on a motorway. He changed gear oil religiously.

Comment: Very helpful tips for my LML Vespa NV 150. My scooter since 1994. Run smoothly with an average 37- 35 KML.This tips surely help me to increase scooter millage. Many thanks to you.I maintain my scooter from the bigining. A K Kunti Birlapur South 24 parganas WB INDIA.

Answer (score 6):

- Tire Pressure correct, less rolling resistance.
- Weight reduction: You, cargo, and extra accessories. The less weight the better the fuel economy.
- Slow smooth acceleration, no jack rabbit starts
- Anticipate stops, let off the accelerator early to start slowing down as opposed to keeping the gas on longer and using the brake harder.
- Eliminate unnecessary idling
- Keep the engine maintained and in tune

Comment: Clean air filter!  Clean air filter.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are talking about a Vespa PX - according to the manual you should get 260Km on a tank. I think this is if you are a very small Italian and travel at a constant 60km/hr. Specs for newer Vespas like the GTS 250 have to conform to EU measurement standards and therefore are more realalistic. Your 150 km is about what I get for mixed riding - I get 130 Km full throttle on motorways.

Agree with the other answer (tire pressure, weight, etc). In addition you can try a windscreen to reduce your drag (or drive around in a race position). Tyre pressure reduces rolling resistance but aerodynamic drag is your biggest enemy. Also avoid puffy jackets (you should be wearing a motorcycle jacket for protection anyway).

As an example my wife and I road for 100km on similar Vespa's, I had a screen and she didn't, I used 1 litre less. The screen also makes you go faster :)

Comment: I have used all the above non-engine customizations, but I am taking care of my vespa in another level also, the engine part. The screen incerases your top speed ~5km which is really strange but it works. Another try we did with a friend is to fill with holes and cut most of the front. Minizing resistance of the face increased our top speed by ~10km :) as long as fuel consumption. And yes I am talking about a px 200 an lml 150 and a vb50(aka vespino 50cc), by using a hallmeter we were able to adjust the carburateur for optimal consumption.

Answer (score 1):

I usually get 220km per tank at about a 80kmh average start to stop including 100kmph of 30kms on the freeway everyday.  i do 500km a week. run a pipe and porting on an otherwise standad bike PX200.  I recon at 60kmph and taking things easy I would get about 300km on the tank but that would be a long ride...

Answer (score 1):

Usually Vespa PX will give approximately 30-35KMPL, since you are getting 25KMPL I recommend you to check the air filter and the spark plug. This particular model is not available in our country, so I may be wrong somewhere. But I am giving you the basic tips which is suitable for all the automotive.

1. Check the air filter if it is too much dusty or oily(Happens in some vehicles) replace it
2. Check the spark plug- if it is highly carbon coated remove the carbon using thin files or sand papers and maintain the spark gap. If possible replace it.
3. Check the idle engine beat(rhythm) if it is not even adjust the AFR (Air Fuel Adjustment) till you get the similarly repeated rhythm, in the same time maintain the engine rpm between 650-800.
4. Check the clutch if the clutch is too tight or loose adjust the clutch cable to bring it to the regular.

---

Possibly this will help you to increase the KMPL.

---

All the best.